# Powershell script for SCVMM

Tags: powershell

I am getting a list of VMS and its attributes using PowerShell script from SCVMM. i want calculate how much time a VM was switched off in a day or in 1 hr.
Please help me know how to calculate the switched off duration for each VM in case it is switched off. Below script is running in every 1hr.

Below is my script .

```
# CHANGE
# Specify the VMM Server
#Write-Host “Connecting to VMM server.....”
$VMMServer="calo-infvmm-01.calocosn.local"
$a = ((get-date).ToUniversalTime()).ToString("yyyyMMddTHHmmss")

$clouds = Get-SCCloud -VMMServer $VMMServer

#Write-Host “Connected to VMM server successffully..”

$vmHeader = [string]::Concat("VMId",",","SubscriptionId",",","VMName",",","OperatingSystem",",","Memory(MB)",",","CPUCount",",","DiskUsed(GB)",",","DiskAllocated(GB)",",","StorageClassification",",","Owner",",","CreationTime",",","SampleTime",",","Status")
Write-Output $vmHeader

ForEach ($cloud in $clouds) 
{
    $VMs = Get-scVirtualMachine -Cloud $cloud
    ForEach ($VM in $VMs) 
    {
        #if ($VM.Name -ne "TestCCE")
        #{
        #    continue;
        #}
        $size = 0
        $maxSize = 0
        $classification = "Standard"
        #Write-Output $VM
        ForEach ($disk in $VM.VirtualHardDisks) 
        {
            $classification = $disk.Classification
            $size += $disk.Size / 1gb

            $parentDisk = $disk.ParentDisk
            while($parentDisk)
            {
            $size += $parentDisk.Size / 1gb
            $parentDisk = $parentDisk.ParentDisk
            }

            $maxSize += $disk.MaximumSize / 1gb
        }
        # CHANGE
        # After the test works, we will acquire additional variables from VMM.        
        $vmText = [string]::Concat($vm.ID,",",$vm.UserRoleID,",",$vm.Name,",",$vm.OperatingSystem,",",$vm.Memory,",",$vm.CPUCount,",",$size,",",$maxSize,",",$classification,",",$vm.Owner,",",$vm.CreationTime,",",$a,",",$vm.Status)
        Write-Output $vmText
    }
}
```

Comment: As i mentioned , i am getting the status , but it is not giving the duration for which VM was off. i mean one VM was off for 2 hr another 1 hr like that.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately this isn't possible as it isn't a value returned by the cmdlet used, nor is there one that I can find that will show how long a VM has been offline.

Comment: Thanks for your answer . Any other way of calculating it dynamically using powershell

Comment: the only way to get the results you're looking for would be quite impractical really, you would need to run the powershell every second or minute and get it to read the status and if it returns offline write the date to an output file of sorts, but again this is really impractical, i would recommend investing in some monitoring software to do this, or maybe look for some freeware that would do it, there are options out there, but unfortunately i dont believe powershell is the right one.